# Sending custom email to multiple email address issue

Tags: email, magento-1

This is my code:

```
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
        $mail->setToName('My Name');
        $mail->setToEmail('email1@gmail.com','email2@gmail.com');
//        $mail->setToEmail($this->getStoreSalesEmail(), $this->getCustomerEmail());
        $mail->setBody($html);
        $mail->setSubject('You have changed your subscription date');
        $mail->setFromEmail('noreply@myemail.com');
//        $mail->setFromName("Msg to Show on Subject");
        $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format
```

I received the email to this address: email1@gmail.com. But for email2@gmail.com I do not receive any email. Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send using below code:

```
$recipients = [
    'rec1@gmail.com' => 'Recipient1 Name',
    'rec2@gmail.com' => 'Recipient2 Name'
];

Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->sendTransactional(
    $templateId,
    $sender,
    array_keys($recipients),
    array_values($recipients),
    $vars,
    $store->getId()
);
```

**EDIT:**

```
$mail->setToEmail(array('email1@gmail.com','email2@gmail.com'));
```

Comment: I am not using a template. I am just sending an email with a short text to multiple addresses.  Thats why i am using Mage::getModel('core/email'), not Mage::getModel('core/email_template')

Comment: updated answer check it

Comment: Thx a lot , this works for me :)